# why is flag being not noticed?

Tags: support

I raised a question on AE https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110239/108847 and it was put **[On hold]** . I realised that it was really not clear for others to understand what i was trying to ask. Later I made several changes and tried to fix all possible errors in that question. But even now it's not being noticed.

Is there a limit (of number of days) to remove **[On hold]** ?

and now it is closed.Please help.

Comment: The Mod you pinged hasn't been seen since yesterday as it seems and other Mods are not going to know your edit (I'm not sure, only speculating), so may be you should wait for him to come back and see your edit.

Comment: Thanks @Firelord , even I think that maybe other Mods can't see the edited version. Is there any other way I can tell him

Comment: The way I read the question, I'm not sure I understand how it's directly Android related. It sounds like you need help configuring your router, as I currently see it.

Comment: I think I understand what do you want on your question, but that's after reading it a few times. I have a feeling that "via router" on the title and the second question "*can anyone help me to limit the data usage from router (limit being shared by all connected devices are different)*" gave a wrong hint to your question, that you want to set the limit *from the router*. I revised your question to make it clearer that you to set it from your Android device.

Comment: @eldarerathis , I see no such configuration settings in my router. So I thought there might be some app which keeps a watch on the Internet limit. Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that we misunderstood each other in the comments.  However, requests to recommend an app for a particular task are off-topic here.  I am not sure that such an app exists, but it's possible.